# How to quote path for Start-Process over cmd.exe?

Tags: powershell

Why does

```
Start-Process -Wait 'C:\scripts\install.cmd'
```

work

adn the following does not

```
Start-Process -Wait 'C:\scripts(1)\install.cmd'
```

How to make it work?

Comment: Do you have a folder literally named `scripts(1)`?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, user unzipped...

Comment: It may be due to the file being blocked? Was it downloaded off the internet? Also, what error does it give you when you try to run it

Comment: If it's due to the user unzipping a file, then the issue is likely AlternateDataStreams.  When files are created in certain ways, like being unzipped from an archive or being downloaded off the web, they get a certain attribute assigned.  See this for more info https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/unblock-file?view=powershell-7.1#description

Answer (score -1):

I tried to reproduce but it worked for me. My PowerShell version is 5.1.19041.906. Maybe there is something wrong with the `install.cmd` script?